# Add DataTable Row to DataGridView without binding

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a predefined DataGridView that I need to add rows to from a DataTable without data binding. I am trying to use the `DataGridView.Rows.Add()` method programmatically however, I do not know the column names of the DataTable. The columns in the DataTable are in the same order as the DataGridView but how do I add them to the DataGridView without knowing the column names?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Say your DataGridView exists but has no columns. You can do this:

```
foreach (DataColumn dc in yourDataTable.Columns) {

     yourDataGridView.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

}
```

Then add the row data:

```
foreach(DataRow dr in yourDataTable.Rows) {

     yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);

}
```

Now, if the default textbox column isn't sufficient, you might have to create a column with a different cell template.

Comment: Item.Array did the trick, simple and to the point. Many thanks for the responses!

Comment: The rows works 100%, but the are empty in the data grid view. May I suggest the following for the columns:

    foreach (DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
    {
        int i = dataGridView.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.ToString());
        dataGridView.Columns[i].ValueType = col.DataType;
    }

Answer (score 2):

if your DataGridView haven’t rows and columns., then just

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable
```

will do all job.

if your DataGridView is already bounded to some datasource(if you using DataTable then I presume DataSource is DataTable),

then you need to edit yourDataTable -> add old rows from old DataTable(or from DataGridView if old DataTable not accessible anymore)

```
foreach(DataRow dr in oldDataTable.Rows)
{
    yourDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
yourDataGridView.DataSource = yourDataTable;
```

or edit oldDataTable -> add new rows from yourDataTable, something like:

```
DataTable dtOld = (DataTable)yourDataGridView.DataSource;
foreach(DataRow yourdr in yourDataTable.Rows)
{
    dtOld.Rows.Add(yourdr);
}
yourDataGridView.DataSource = dtOld;
```

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you want to get the column names from the `DataTable` and add the rows to DataGridView from DataTable rows

```
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
            //adding Columns
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("colInt", typeof(int));
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("colDate", typeof(DateTime));
            myDataTable.Columns.Add("colString", typeof(string));

            //adding Rows
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(1, DateTime.Now, "Hello World");

            //to get columns
            foreach (DataColumn col in myDataTable.Columns)
            {
                var c = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { HeaderText = col.ColumnName }; //Let say that the default column template of DataGridView is DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(c);
            }

            //to get rows
            foreach (DataRow row in myDataTable.Rows)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row[0], row[1], row[2]);
            }
```

anyway there's a shortcut 
`dataGridView1.DataSource = myDataTable;`