# vb.net add datatable row to datagridview row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

actually my questiom is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810056/add-datatable-row-to-datagridview-without-binding) case. the different is: i want to add row to three predefined column from datatable, and the other two were a comboboxes, which datasources were already set on page_load

can you explain to me a proper step to achieve this result. i don't asking for code.

what's on my mind now is

1. defined bounded datatable
2. create datarow from the bounded datatable
3. looping the datagridview column ( from index 1 to 3), then adding my datarow value to datagridview rows

please cmiiw, thank you very much

Comment: "i don't asking for code." You're not asking for code? What are you asking for then?

Comment: i mean 'can someone tell me the step-by-step method to achieve it'